# "How to fix "Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "ETag", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was trying to update the cloudfront distribution using the command

`aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config  file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E3I4XTNBFKPSY8`

But it resulted in an error :

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "CallerReference"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Origins"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "DefaultCacheBehavior"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Comment"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Enabled"
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "ETag", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, OriginGroups, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "DistributionConfig", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, OriginGroups, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
```

I have tried removing `Etag` and `DistributionConfig` parameters from the "secrue-ssl" json file, then command got executed but with a new `Etag` value. I don't want neither `Etag` to get modified nor distribution configuration.

Is there any way to fix the issue without deleting the `Etag` and `DistributionConfig` parameters from the json file?

```
{
    "ETag": "E3I4XTNBFKPSY8",
    "DistributionConfig": {
        "Comment": "",
        "CacheBehaviors": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "IsIPV6Enabled": true,
        "Logging": {
            "Bucket": "",
            "Prefix": "",
            "Enabled": false,
            "IncludeCookies": false
        },
        "WebACLId": "",
        "Origins": {
            "Items": [
                {
                    "OriginPath": "",
                    "CustomOriginConfig": {
                        "OriginSslProtocols": {
                            "Items": [
                                "TLSv1",
                                "TLSv1.1",
                                "TLSv1.2"
                            ],
                            "Quantity": 3
                        },
                        "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only",
                        "OriginReadTimeout": 30,
                        "HTTPPort": 80,
                        "HTTPSPort": 443,
                        "OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
                    },
                    "CustomHeaders": {
                        "Quantity": 0
                    },
                    "Id": "ELB-cicdpipeline-646360150",
                    "DomainName": "cicdpipeline-646360150.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
                }
            ],
            "Quantity": 1
        },
        "DefaultRootObject": "",
        "PriceClass": "PriceClass_All",
        "Enabled": true,
        "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
            "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
            "TrustedSigners": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "TargetOriginId": "ELB-cicdpipeline-646360150",
            "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
            "ForwardedValues": {
                "Headers": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "Cookies": {
                    "Forward": "none"
                },
                "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                },
                "QueryString": false
            },
            "MaxTTL": 31536000,
            "SmoothStreaming": false,
            "DefaultTTL": 86400,
            "AllowedMethods": {
                "Items": [
                    "HEAD",
                    "GET"
                ],
                "CachedMethods": {
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD",
                        "GET"
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 2
                },
                "Quantity": 2
            },
            "MinTTL": 0,
            "Compress": false
        },
        "CallerReference": "1562748965921",
        "ViewerCertificate": {
            "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": true,
            "MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1",
            "CertificateSource": "cloudfront"
        },
        "CustomErrorResponses": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "OriginGroups": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "HttpVersion": "http1.1",
        "Restrictions": {
            "GeoRestriction": {
                "RestrictionType": "none",
                "Quantity": 0
            }
        },
        "Aliases": {
            "Quantity": 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is to disable/remove `orginsslprotocols`: SSLV3..

Before modifying the json quantity was "4", now it is changed to value "3".

1. Is there a simple CLI command to modify the only `originsslprotocol`
   value instead of editing json? If not, is there any other method to
   execute above mentioned CLI command without deleting the `Etag` /
   `DistributionConfig` Parameters?
2. Is it possible to fix the issue using a single line AWS CLI
   command (for automation purpose)?

It would be a great help if you share your valuable inputs here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone please help me out on this issue

Comment: can anyone please help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but I have been thrashing around with this problem and AWS's defective documentation (which [tells you to set the config file up wrong](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html) at the top, and only gives the correct answer 60% of the way through the huge document) for hours.

What you *actually* need to do is:

1. Remove this from the beginning of your distribution config JSON file:

```
{
    "Tag": "...",
    "DistributionConfig":
```

2. Remove this from the last line of the same file:

```
}
```

3. Invoke the update-distribution action from the CLI **with the Tag specified with --if-match on the command line**:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id DISTRIBUTION_ID --if-match YOUR_ETAG --distribution-config file://PATH_TO_FILE
```